# How to find the div next to the input box on change event?

Tags: jquery

```
$(document.body).on("change", 'input[type=file]', function () {
    if($(this).next("div").hasClass('imagePreview')) {
        $(this).next("div").remove();
    }
    $(this).after('<div class="imagePreview"></div>');
    var files = !!this.files ? this.files : [];
    if(!files.length || !window.FileReader) return; // no file selected, or no FileReader support
    if(/^image/.test(files[0].type)) { // only image file
        var reader = new FileReader(); // instance of the FileReader
        reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]); // read the local file
        reader.onloadend = function () { // set image data as background of div
            //$(".imagePreview").css("background-image", "url("+this.result+")");
            $(".imagePreview").last().css("background-image", "url(" + this.result + ")");
        }
    }
});
```

Here is jsfiddle link for the above code http://jsfiddle.net/riteshkhadka/K5Gag/3/
The code works great for the continuous upload but it fails when the user upload image in the middle input box after inserting image in first, second, third and so on..
How can I find the current div for the current input type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using `$(".imagePreview").last()` thus your code will always modify the last `imagePreview` element. *I have tried to explain as inserted comments in code*

```
$(document.body).on("change", 'input[type=file]', function () {
    var imagePreview = $(this).parent().find("div.imagePreview"); //Find the imagePreview in parent
    if (imagePreview.length) { //Check element exists
        imagePreview.remove(); //If exists remove that
    }
    $(this).after('<div class="imagePreview"></div>'); //insert element
    imagePreview = $(this).parent().find("div.imagePreview"); //again refer to element
    var files = !! this.files ? this.files : [];
    if (!files.length || !window.FileReader) return; // no file selected, or no FileReader support

    if (/^image/.test(files[0].type)) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
        reader.onloadend = function () {
            imagePreview.css("background-image", "url(" + this.result + ")");
        }
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/a6UGF/)

Comment: Thanks worked as a charm..I had tried earlier assigning to variable but I had failed..Thanks again